# SQL Server Select from a table returned by a query as list of table names

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

If I have these tables below:

**PLAYERS**

```
ID    Name
==    ===========
1     Mick
2     Matt
```

**COACHES**

```
ID    Name
==    ===========
1     Bill
2     Don
```

And I have a script below to find all tables that has a column called "Name":

```
SELECT t.name AS table_name FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
WHERE c.name LIKE 'Name'
```

Which returns the following:

```
table_name
===========
PLAYERS
COACHES
```

How can I select all the rows from both tables returned by the query above?

Comment: What is ur expected output?

Comment: I want to print all the columns from both tables without having to type select from each table off the given query's result one by one.
Your solution below is what I am avoiding.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will have to use dynamic sql, try something like this:

```
declare @t table( tablename varchar(50))
declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql = ''

insert into @t
SELECT t.name AS table_name FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
WHERE c.name LIKE 'Name'

select @sql = @sql + 'Select * From ' + tablename + ' union ' from @t

--remove the trailing 'union'
Select @sql = substring(@sql, 1, len(@sql) - 6)

exec (@sql)
```

The above script creates and executes the following sql

```
select * from coaches
union
select * from players
```

Since we are using `union` here, it is important that all your tables that have `name` as column is of same structure.

See more about dynamic sql from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx

Comment: That works, thanks heaps! Apparently there is no function or anything to link a string to an actual SQL table.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT p.Id,p.Name,c.Id,c.Name
FROM Players p JOIN Coaches c
ON p.Id=c.Id
```

May be this can help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this is exactly what I don't want. I just can't type each entry if I have 100 tables.